Cant find general solution to my own probability game
I created a probability game as an analog for another problem I was working on. I know how to (manually) calculate the answers, but it's a daunting task and is nearly impossible past 4 players. I keep searching for a general formula, or even a known sequence (OEIS) that would provide the general answer, to no avail.
Here's the puzzle:
Ten people sit around in a circle. Each player writes down another players number in order to eliminate them. All players show their numbers at once, and eliminated players leave. That concludes the first round. Players cannot choose themselves for elimination.
Rounds continue until there is either $1$ or $0$ winners to the game.
What is the probability of there being a winner given "x" starting players (I used ten in my example).
So far I have this table:



#Players
#Outcomes
$0$
$1$
$2$
$3$




$1$
$1$
$0$
$1$
$0$
$0$


$2$
$1$
$1$
$0$
$0$
$0$


$3$
$8$
$2$
$6$
$0$
$0$


$4$
$81$
$6$
$54$
$21$
$0$



(The number in the last four columns means the amount of remaining players after a round.)
So, for example: a $4$ player game has
a probability of $\frac{6}{81}$ to go to 0 players, a probability of $\frac{54}{81}$ to go to 1 players, a probability of $\frac{21}{81}$ to go to 2 players, and
a zero percent chance of any other outcome.
That means there's a $\frac{54}{81}$ probability of having a winner with four starting players, since zero- and two-player rounds have no winners.
This creates the following solutions from the above table:
$1$ player - $\frac{1}{1}$ probability of a winner
$2$ players - $\frac{0}{1}$ probability of a winner
$3$ players - $\frac{3}{4}$ probability of a winner
$4$ players - $\frac{2}{3}$ probability of a winner
Is there a way to continue my original table, or even to solve for the final results?
I've found the following already: the number of outcomes for a round with more than $1$ player is $(P-1)^P$, where $P$ is the number of players, and the probability of having $0$ winners for a round is $\frac{(P-1)!}{(P-1)^P}$
Thanks all!
EDIT. This problem was answered completely below, which means some of the values I provided for a 4 player game were incorrect. (It was very hard to calculate!)
Also, my formula for # of outcomes was correct, but not the formula for having $0$ winners for a round.

The probabilities I get for 4 players are 9/81, 48/81, 24/81 rather than 6/81, 54/81, 21/81. You might be missing, for example, the possibility that all four players eliminate each other in two pairs, rather than in a cycle.

If $p_n$ is the probability that there is a winner, then the first few values of $p_n$ are
$$
  p_1 = 1,\; p_2 = 0,\; p_3 = \frac34,\; p_4 = \frac{16}{27}, \; p_5 = \frac{15}{32},\; p_6 = \frac{11704}{28125},\; \dots
$$
For more values of $p_n$, see the OEIS; A372486 has the numerators and A372487 has the denominators.
There doesn't seem to be a closed-form solution, nor does $p_n$ converge as $n \to \infty$. In fact, the behavior of $p_n$ in the long run is rather bizarre. The paper The asymptotics of group Russian roulette goes into the details; the short story is that there's an oscillating behavior, but the lengths of the oscillations grow exponentially.

Group Russian Roulette... I love it

Just curious.. I searched the OEIS already.. Do you know of a recorded sequence that completes the triangle in my original table? Starting with 2 players and using correct values this time....  1, 2, 6, 9, 48, 24  ?

I don't think the full triangle appears anywhere. The $0$ column is A000166, the sequence of derangements: here, we want the numbers written down to be a permutation, so that everyone is eliminated, but it must be fixed-point-free because nobody can write down their own number. Further columns are more obscurve; the $1$ column is A037184, but the other columns don't have sequences. The diagonal where only $2$ players are eliminated is A001788.
